# c# Struct Ref to prevent copy

Tags: c#, struct, copy, ref

I have the need to have a private struct member within a class and am looking for a way to **access** this struct member, without performing a copy.

The reason for this is that the struct is used as an interface to a c dll.

```
public class MyCDllApi
{
    // Marshalled struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DllData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public byte data1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public byte data2;
        // ...
        // lots more; this is really a LARGE struct
    }

    // DLL Function call
    [DllImport("MyC.dll",  CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int do_some_work(ref DllData data);

    public void doSomeWork()
    {
        do_some_work(ref m_dllData);
    }
    public DllData getData();

    private DllData m_dllData;
}

public class MyProg
{
    static void Main(String args[])
    {
        MyC_DllApi m_dllApi = new MyCDllApi();
        m_dllApi.doSomeWork();
        DllData data = m_dllApi.getData();

        // Use data
    }
}
```

I was thinking that I could box the struct and return an object from getData(), however this means that a cast would be required.

I was also thinking that I could contain the struct within a class and this could be passed around as reference, however any method provided to retrieve the struct member would perform a copy.

Another idea is to make m_dllData public.

Could someone advise me of the normal solution in such cases in c#, i.e. the equivalent of returning "const &" in C++. Am I right to want to avoid creating copy of the struct for performance reasons? I can pass a struct by ref as a function argument. Can I not return a ref to a class member struct?

EDIT

**Just to clarify, in this case I am using a struct because this complies with the API of the DLL and I think it is good to be consistent with this API. I am not asking for a way to replace this with a class. Similarly I am not looking for a solution which makes the class more complex.**

**I'd like MyCDllApi to be a simple unintelligent c# wrapper to a C dll. I am asking if the there is any reasonable way to avoid the struct copy everytime an external object accesses this class to retrieve DllData. i.e. in a similar manner to "const &" in C++.**

**If such a solution/pattern is not commonly used or appropriate in C# then this is fine. My program can handle the overhead of the struct copy. I just though I would ask the question.**

Thanks

Comment: That struct is so small, why are you worrying about it being copied?

Comment: You may want to rename your question to be more descriptive of the problem. Also as a side note, C# standard is `MethodName()` not `methodName()` and Hungarian notation is a bit antequated.

Comment: The struct shown is an example. I kept it small for simplicity. The real structs are quite large.

Comment: It already works that way, the struct is blittable.  So the pinvoke marshaller will pass a pointer to the struct as stored inside the class object, the native code scribbles directly into the GC heap.  You are trying to optimize something that doesn't need any help.  Only optimize code if you *know* you have a perf problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not concerned about the performance when I call the 'C' function. It is the accessor function 'getData' that I am concerned about.

Comment: Even if you box to an object (which requires a copy), once you unbox (i.e. downcast), the value is copied to a local on the stack.

Comment: You could use a `class` with `SequentialLayout`. That is already a 'pointer', so define it as `do_some_work(DllData data)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. A class with sequential layout is interesting and would work. However I wasn't looking for a way to avoid using a struct. I was wondering what the recommended pattern is for returning a struct but avoiding the copy. Perhaps this is not possible or recommended in c# in the way that it is in c++, which is fine. The overhead of the copy can be tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it sounds like you have three options:

1. Use a `class` with `[SequentialLayout]`; see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) example.
2. Don't try to return the entire struct in `getData()`, rather just the pieces that are really interesting to callers.  A variant on this would be to pass in a `Func<>` (or `Action<>`) to operate on the struct.  Both techniques avoid copying.
3. Do C++ work in C++; implement `doSomeWork()` in C++/CLI instead of C#.  This also avoids duplicating a (large) struct from a **.h** file in C#.

Comment: Thanks. I have no scope for changing the dll so can't do option 1. The objective of my class is to simple implement the c#/c interface i.e. providing a wrapper to the c dll and let external classes do more meaningful work. I don't want to provide restrictions to users of the class and don't want to perform any functionality inside MyCDllApi other than being a dumb wrapper withing the dll.

Comment: @user1400716: marshaling through p/invoke is going to involve copying the data, period. .NET's not going to let your C++ shoot your C# in the foot. And you can marshal the data as a `class` as easily as a `struct`; p/invoke doesn't care (nor does C++...for unmanaged code, `class` and `struct` have exactly the same implementation anyway). IMHO, Dan's #3 suggestion is probably as close as you're going to get to your desired goal, but there's not enough detail in the question to know for sure.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: It's possible to marshal blittable types by reference; on the .NET side they're passed as a `ref` parameter, and the native side they're declared as pointers.  When .NET passes by reference a struct which is contained within an object's field, the object in question will be pinned until the method returns.

Comment: @supercat: thanks, right you are. In that scenario, .NET does let your C++ shoot your C# in the foot. So, basically: the OP's code already does what he's asking for it to do, as long as he sticks with `struct`.